# A simple registration form in MySQL command line connected to Eclipse, but the register data was not stored in my database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

The Java file name is `Regis.java` and the HTML file name is `Reg.html`

```js
package Bk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException;

public class Regis extends HttpServlet{
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest rq,HttpServletResponse rs)
 throws ServletException,IOException{
  rs.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw=rs.getWriter();
  String s1=rq.getParameter("uname"); 
  String s2=rq.getParameter("pass");
  String s3=rq.getParameter("age");
  String s4=rq.getParameter("mob");
  try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/p","root","8993"); 
   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into rsm values(?,?,?,?)");
   ps.setString(1,s1);
   ps.setString(2,s2);
   ps.setString(3,s3);
   ps.setString(4,s4);
   int i=ps.executeUpdate();
   if(i>0){
    pw.print("ur registation is successful !!!!!");
   }
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }pw.close();
 }
}
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Bnk</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Reg.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>re</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Bk.Regis</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>re</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/registation</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="registation" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="uname"><br><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age"><br><br>
Mobile no:<input type="text" name="mob"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="registation">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this registration form, I entered the register data, that data was not stored my MySQL database. Database name is `p` and the table name is `rsm`. Each time run this program exception error will be occurred.

Comment: I've missed something... are you ask a Javascript or Java question?

Comment: Are you using mysql connector?

Comment: yes i have mysql connector.